# When setting up Proxy Server, how to ensure that all network traffic is routed through that PC?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy, wireless-router, lan

I have around 15 PCs (some Windows 7 and rest Macs) connected in a wireless lan.

I have setup one of the Win 7 PC as Proxy Server.

How do I ensure that all machines in the network connect through this proxy server for getting internet access?

Comment: Can you explain why you would want all computers to connect through one server? That will probably be very slow due to limited wireless bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers have a proxy setting available.  Set your browsers to use the proxy.

Comment: What about other apps that don't allow you to specify a proxy and don't use IE's setting either?

Answer (score 0):

Make the machine a gateway and set other machines to use its IP address as gateway (in network settings)

Comment: How do I make my PC a gateway?

Comment: right click on the internet connection in network connections and select share this connection. Atleast that was how I did it in windows xp