# On Windows, how to ensure all traffic from mobile hotspot go through local proxy server?

Tags: networking, proxy, hotspot

Some devices (phone, pad, etc) connect to my Windows machine through the mobile hotspot. Now I ran `xray.exe` as a proxy server in my windows machine, listening to port 10809. How to make traffic from mobile hotspot go through this proxy server?

Either by configuration, application or code is acceptable.

---

**Update**: I tried [this link](https://superuser.com/a/580109/869480), but did not work:
In "change adapter settings" page, the `Ethernet` is the adapter for internet connection, and `Local connection* 15` is the adapter for mobile hotspot. I edit the property of `Ethernet` to share connection and select the `Local connection* 15`.

Comment: Explain how you've set up the mobile hotspot on your Windows machine.